# Downloading time series of market caps (Python)

Tags: programming, market-data, market-capitalization

I know that is possible to download the market capitalisation os stocks using the "pandas_datareader" library: `data.get_quote_yahoo`. However, this command gives me the last data of capitalisations for the tickers I provide while I need the whole time series of stock capitalisations.

There's a way to get it directly?

Comment: You'll find an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815864/downloading-a-companies-market-cap-from-yahoo